# Which has higher variance, coin toss vs dice roll?

Tags: probability, variance

Dusting off some high school stats and getting confused over the following:

Two betting games:

> - Pick right side of coin, even-money bet ($p = 0.5$, $q= 0.5$),
> - Pick right value in a 10-sided die, pays 9x original bet ($p = 0.1$, $q=0.9$),
>
> where $p$ is probability of picking the right choice, $q$ is probably picking wrong.

After $n$ bets, the winnings follows a binomial distribution for both games.
The variance I believe should 
$$npq,$$

which is $0.25n$ for game 1
and $0.09n$ for game 2.

Both games has expected winnings of 0, but intuitively I know game 2 has higher variance, so what's wrong with the variance calculation?

I am sure I missed something really obvious.

Answer (score 3):

The number of games won is binomially distributed, not the winnings. For instance, the variance of the number of coin toss games won out of $n$ games is 
$$
n \times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} = 0.25 n.
$$
Further, the variance of the number of dice games won out of $n$ games is
$$
n \times \frac{1}{10} \times \frac{9}{10} = 0.09n.
$$

But the *payout* is $2b$ for each coin toss game and $10b$ for each dice game, where $b$ dollars is your initial bet.  Therefore, the variance in the payout for the coin toss game is 
$$
(2b)^2 \times 0.25 n = b^2 n,
$$
and the variance in the payout for the dice game is
$$
(10b)^2 \times 0.09 n = 9b^2 n.
$$